# Build Qt application for Android - move failed

Tags: android, qt, makefile, qmake

I've faced some strange error while building my Qt/QML application for Android.
At the moment I have 2 configurations:
 - MinGW 5.3.0 32 bit
 - Android armeabi v7a (GCC 4.9)

I can compile/run MinGW version without problem.
But when I compile Android version I get some strange error. And interestingly, the error occurs when compiled lib should be moved to DESTDIR folder. The compilation itself passed without problem.

In details:

*.pro file:

```
QT += gui widgets
TARGET = MyLib
TEMPLATE = lib
DESTDIR=$$PWD/../lib

SOURCES += \    
   ...
HEADERS += \
    ...
```

In project setting `make` defined as `C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk-r17\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make so in console I've run that as following:

```
> C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk-r17\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make all
```

The compilation passed w/o problems but I still get error:

```
move libMyLib.so  ..\..\MyProject\lib\
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, move libMyLib.so "..\..\MyProject\lib ", ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: [..\..\MyProject\lib\libMyLib.so] Error 2 (ignored)
```

It looks that script cannot move compiled file to the destination folder. Ok, I've tried to do that manually. Here, in the same console window I did:

```
move libMyLib.so  ..\..\MyProject\lib\
        1 file(s) moved.
```

And the file to my astonishment has moved without problem!
But why make script failed at the same command??

in `Makefile` that defined as:

```
MOVE          = move
...
-$(MOVE) $(TARGET)  ..\..\MyProject\lib\
```

So it looks that make uses the same `move` as I used in console.

How can I avoid this error?

Environment:

- Windows 10 x64
- Qt 5.10.1

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this issue? I'm facing the same problem...Edit: Oh, I didn't realise you asked this just yesterday! Thought this would be a more or less common question

Comment: My environment is Windows 10 x64 also, but I am using Qt 5.11

Comment: Furthermore, I have tested the very same project with Qt 5.8, and it executed the `move` instruction perfectly fine....

Comment: I asked Qt support and they say that `make` should be from MinGW ie. mingw32-make.exe. But my config that I didn't change anyway uses make from Android NDK. I'm going to test that.

Comment: There is an old Qt bug report about this issue but unfortunately not good solutions to fix it: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35713

Comment: This Qt bug report has a workaround: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69255

It is marked as fixed in Qt 5.11.2, but it's still present in Qt 5.12.0.